# Package dependency problem (offline install of wireless drivers)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, broadcom

I have a friend wanting to install Ubuntu 10.10 as a dual-boot with Windows through Wubi. Unfortunately, he has a wireless card with a Broadcom chipset, and needs to install the drivers. There is no other way for him to connect to the internet; he cannot connect via Ethernet or another Wi-Fi dongle/card.

I generated a Synaptic download script for what I think are the appropriate packages, and he downloaded the `.deb`s to `\wifi\packages` from Windows. He then ran these commands:

```
kieran@ubuntu:~$ cd /host/wifi
kieran@ubuntu:/host/wifi$ sudo dpkg -i packages/*.deb
[sudo] password for kieran: 
(Reading database ... 120178 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bcmwl-kernel-source 5.60.48.36+bdcom-0ubuntu3 (using .../bcmwl-kernel-source_5.60.48.36+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Preparing to replace broadcom-sta-common 5.10.91.9.3-3 (using .../broadcom-sta-common_5.10.91.9.3-3_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement broadcom-sta-common ...
Preparing to replace broadcom-sta-source 5.10.91.9.3-3 (using .../broadcom-sta-source_5.10.91.9.3-3_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement broadcom-sta-source ...
Preparing to replace build-essential 11.4build1 (using .../build-essential_11.4build1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement build-essential ...
Preparing to replace cvs 1:1.12.13-12ubuntu1 (using .../cvs_1.12.13-12ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement cvs ...
Preparing to replace debhelper 7.4.15ubuntu1 (using .../debhelper_7.4.15ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement debhelper ...
Preparing to replace diffstat 1.47-1build1 (using .../diffstat_1.47-1build1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement diffstat ...
Preparing to replace dkms 2.1.1.2-2fakesync1 (using .../dkms_2.1.1.2-2fakesync1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dkms ...
Preparing to replace dpkg-dev 1.15.5.6ubuntu4.3 (using .../dpkg-dev_1.15.5.6ubuntu4.3_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dpkg-dev ...
Preparing to replace fakeroot 1.14.4-1ubuntu1 (using .../fakeroot_1.14.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fakeroot ...
Preparing to replace g++ 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1 (using .../g++_4.4.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement g++ ...
Preparing to replace g++-4.4 4.4.3-4ubuntu5 (using .../g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement g++-4.4 ...
Preparing to replace gettext 0.17-8ubuntu3 (using .../gettext_0.17-8ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gettext ...
Preparing to replace html2text 1.3.2a-14build1 (using .../html2text_1.3.2a-14build1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement html2text ...
Preparing to replace intltool-debian 0.35.0+20060710.1 (using .../intltool-debian_0.35.0+20060710.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement intltool-debian ...
Preparing to replace libmail-sendmail-perl 0.79.16-1 (using .../libmail-sendmail-perl_0.79.16-1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmail-sendmail-perl ...
Preparing to replace libstdc++6-4.4-dev 4.4.3-4ubuntu5 (using .../libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libstdc++6-4.4-dev ...
Preparing to replace libsys-hostname-long-perl 1.4-2 (using .../libsys-hostname-long-perl_1.4-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libsys-hostname-long-perl ...
Preparing to replace patch 2.6-2ubuntu1 (using .../patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement patch ...
Preparing to replace po-debconf 1.0.16 (using .../po-debconf_1.0.16_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement po-debconf ...
Preparing to replace quilt 0.48-5 (using packages/quilt_0.48-5_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement quilt ...
Setting up broadcom-sta-common (5.10.91.9.3-3) ...
Setting up cvs (1:1.12.13-12ubuntu1) ...
Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script
The package cvs should be rebuilt with new debhelper to get trigger support
Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script
The package cvs should be rebuilt with new debhelper to get trigger support
Setting up diffstat (1.47-1build1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.1.1.2-2fakesync1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dpkg-dev:
 dpkg-dev depends on xz-utils; however:
  Package xz-utils is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dpkg-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up fakeroot (1.14.4-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-4.4:
 g++-4.4 depends on gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5); however:
  Version of gcc-4.4-base on system is 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.
 g++-4.4 depends on gcc-4.4 (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5); however:
  Version of gcc-4.4 on system is 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.
 g++-4.4 depends on libmpfr1ldbl; however:
  Package libmpfr1ldbl is not installed.
dpkg: error processing g++-4.4 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gettext (0.17-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up html2text (1.3.2a-14build1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6-4.4-dev:
 libstdc++6-4.4-dev depends on gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5); however:
  Version of gcc-4.4-base on system is 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.
 libstdc++6-4.4-dev depends on g++-4.4 (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5); however:
  Package g++-4.4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libstdc++6-4.4-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libsys-hostname-long-perl (1.4-2) ...
Setting up patch (2.6-2ubuntu1) ...

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
 build-essential depends on dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5); however:
  Package dpkg-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing build-essential (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debhelper:
 debhelper depends on dpkg-dev (>= 1.14.19); however:
  Package dpkg-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing debhelper (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++:
 g++ depends on g++-4.4 (>= 4.4.3-1); however:
  Package g++-4.4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing g++ (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of broadcom-sta-source:
 broadcom-sta-source depends on debhelper (>= 7); however:
  Package debhelper is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing broadcom-sta-source (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.60.48.36+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.60.48.36+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 2.6.35-22-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 2.6.35-22-generic

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 2.6.35-22-generic (i686)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom/build/ for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms.py", line 57, in 
    report.write(open(apport.fileutils.make_report_path(report), 'w'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
dpkg: error processing bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up libmail-sendmail-perl (0.79.16-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Setting up intltool-debian (0.35.0+20060710.1) ...
Setting up po-debconf (1.0.16) ...
Setting up quilt (0.48-5) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 4 changed doc-base file(s)...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dpkg-dev
 g++-4.4
 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
 build-essential
 debhelper
 g++
 broadcom-sta-source
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The `xz-utils` package would not install separately either. Is there any way to solve the dependency problem, or an easier way to configure the wireless card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the line `libstdc++6-4.4-dev depends on gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5); however:
  Version of gcc-4.4-base on system is 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.` I am 99% confident  you are trying to install 10.04 (Lucid) packages on a 10.10 (Maverick) system.

This is almost always a bad idea.

I'm not sure about the details of your *Synaptic download script* but I hope you can use this information to modify the script to work.

Comment: D'oh. It turns out my install (where I used Synaptic to generate the download script) is 10.04, rather than 10.10. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -2):

use `dkpg adding --ignore-depends`

Comment: This needs a bit more detail on what to do and what this does.

Comment: Is the syntax broken here?