# Installing wireless drivers without internet access

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install and download drivers without internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet)

(This is related to [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8344/package-dependency-problem-offline-install-of-wireless-drivers); my approach there didn't work.)

My friend has (I'm quite sure) a Broadcom wireless chipset. However, he doesn't have any wired internet access on the machine, so his only option is to boot into Windows (he is using Wubi) and download packages there.

This means we can't use the Hardware Drivers dialog to install the drivers. He can't fetch the repository information, so the Broadcom driver packages aren't showing up in Synaptic.

Is there any way to get Wi-Fi working?