# No Internet On 12.04.1

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install and download drivers without internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet)

I have no internet on Ubuntu 12.04.1 so i'm on a desktop so I got to install a .exe program to run my wireless card for my desktop so I got internet access, But I can't seem to download wine or its source files. If I do I put on my usb and boot into Ubuntu but then when I try to open it I get the programs source files etc. Anyone who could help me Please do :|  ( I can't install wine from software center since I have no connection online).

Note : I can download my stuff on windows 8 boot so I can transfer files to my usb to run on Ubuntu.

Comment: What does installing wine have to do with getting wireless working in Ubuntu? Also, this is [probably a duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/146425/12864). Can you please try the answer there and see if it helps?

Comment: If I install WIne It would let me run the .exe program so I can install my internet program then I have internet on My Ubuntu OS and can do whatever like usual.

Comment: Are you sure the windows driver for your wifi adapter you are trying to install will work on Ubuntu? I think it would be better to say us which is your wifi adapter and if your machine is 32 or 64 bits and try to find a Linux driver for it.

Comment: I got My Machine is 32 Bit Ubuntu Running and the wifi adpater is Netgear® RangeMax Dual Band Wireless-N USB Adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Ubuntu drivers from the Additional Drivers utility. That might help.

You can open Additional Drivers by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (the <kbd>Windows</kbd>) key (or clicking the home button at the upper-left corner of the screen) to open the Unity Dash, then type the first few letters (`additi`...). **Additional Drivers** will appear and you can click on it to run it.