# WiFi driver help

Tags: wireless

My wifi driver does not work. I have already uninstalled windows and I can't get any internet access. The only option may be to install a new one but how. The only internet access I have is on my phone. Please help.

Comment: This answer here: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet" might help you out

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like help finding the driver, we need to know which driver you need.

Right now what you're really asking is how to get the driver through your phone.  You have two options:

A. Usb tethering (accessing the internet through your phone's data plan)

B. Using your phone as a usb drive, downloading the file, and then copy pasting it from your phone's drive to your computer's hard drive.