# How to install wireless drivers Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, 16.04, broadcom

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on my Desktop PC that has a built in wireless adapter in the motherboard (Broadcom 802.11ac 14e4:43b1).

Right now I do not have the installation disk nor access to ethernet so the below post did not work for me.
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

I found this drivers https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7

and i am wondering how do i install this offline.

Please help, I am a complete beginner and would be really helpful if you can elaborate.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: See this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet/8557#8557

Answer (score -1):

Here are some commands that may help. There is also a link for the video!

~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

Driver - Card/Model

*STA - BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225, BCM43227, **BCM43228
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

- b43 - BCM4306/3, BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4318, BCM4320
  sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
  sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
  sudo modprobe b43

b43legacy - BCM4301, BCM4306, BCM4306/2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlLS8d4Z09c

Good luck with it.