# Wifi drivers not working/ wifi disappeared in panel

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

my computer was working for weeks until today when I tried to connect to the internet but noticed that it would not reconnect. When I look into the wireless connection panel it does not show any wireless options anymore. I have tried reinstalling the rtl8821ae drivers, no luck. If anyone needs additional information, please ask!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your exact solution but I have faced a similar problem and I am fixed it. Try this link to solve your Wifi Issue.
[WIFI Driver install](https://askubuntu.com/a/616548/659769)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem a day later by downgrading my kernel version, I believe I was on something like 4.12 generic and I downgraded to 4.4.0-79-generic. This solved my issue for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo -s
modprobe -r rtl8821ae
modprobe rt8821ae
```

if all else fails, try downgrading your kernel.

Comment: Sorry, I already fixed this issue by downgrading my kernel as I have said above.