# I changed my username and it deleted everything in /media/. How do I repopulate it?

Tags: 16.04, media

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. I changed my username following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username).

No problem.

I then used [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet) to configure wifi (I've done this many times before but not after changing my username), but noticed that there was nothing under `/media/`. I'm guessing it was deleted by changing my username.

How do I repopulate `/media/` so that I can install wifi?

Thanks.

Comment: What was in `/media` previously?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen `sudo dpkg -i /media/username/volname/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_*.deb` then 
`sudo dpkg -i /media/username/volname/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb` are the commands required to install wifi. Apparently the packages required to install wifi are supposed to be under `/media/`? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: No there are not! Were these downloaded by you into a `USB` device as this is where Ubuntu would normally mount it when plugged into your system? please re-plugin the device and there should show up as usual...

Comment: If you insert a removable media, such as a USB harddrive, it will typically be mounted in the /media directory under your username.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `/media` directory in a fresh install is already empty and should have no effect on the Wifi.

If you absolutely have to do what that guide in the second link said, hunt down that Live USB Stick with the Ubuntu image on it and plug it into your machine. Once you plug it in (assuming you're using the Desktop version of Ubuntu), the drive should automatically mount at `/media/<username>/<volname>`. Then you can run the `dpkg` commands listed in the guide.