# How to fix wifi adapter RTL8723DE and dependency issues on new dual-boot install Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, software-installation

I have recently installed Ubuntu only to find that my wifi-adapter can't be detected. I have tried various methods mentioned online but nothing seems to work. But the common error I receive is that the dependencies are missing.

One of the first methods that I tried was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet), where the top-voted answer suggests using commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/username/volname/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_*.deb
sudo dpkg -i /media/username/volname/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb
```

I get the following error:

[image]
As it says packages like dpkg-dev, gcc are not installed/configured.

Just to confirm I check if a particular package is not installed using:

```
dpkg -i dpkg-dev
```

And I get the following result:
[image]

I don't understand the result entirely but it seems `dpkg-dev` is installed but not correctly.

So here's my dilemma where something shows that a dependency is not installed but on checking, it is indeed installed. But even if I try to install build-essential, gcc, dpkg-dev with a dev file either with apt-get or Ubuntu Software it doesn't work. With apt-get it says that other dependencies are missing and I'm stuck in this endless cycle of unmet dependencies.

What do I do from here? My primary goal is to get my wifi working set up my development environment on Ubuntu. But I can't do anything without the wifi here.

I have also tried downloading driver my Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter Wireless (git project) and installing it using make as instructed on this [page](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307).

I get the following error when I use make:
[image]

and using dkms doesn't work either.

These are not the only solutions and resources I have tried. I have browsed Youtube, various forums but none seem to match my requirements or solve my problem. I am a newbie to Ubuntu and decided to dual boot because of all the praise I see for Linux about the ease of development on here. But I can't even get started.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem. I just want to get my wifi working and get my initial setup on Ubuntu. Please let me know if any additional information is required.

PS: I don't have an Ethernet Port. So wired connection is not possible.

Following is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106742/discussion-on-question-by-mohit-motwani-how-to-fix-wifi-adapter-rtl8723de-and-de).